# boolean indexing from a subset of a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, boolean

I have an array of names, along with a corresponding array of data. From the array of names, there is also a smaller subset of names:

```
data = np.array([75., 49., 80., 87., 99.])
arr1 = np.array(['Bob', 'Joe', 'Mary', 'Ellen', 'Dick'], dtype='|S5')
arr2 = np.array(['Mary', 'Dick'], dtype='|S5')
```

I am trying to make a new array of data corresponding only to the names that appear in arr2.  This is what I have been able to come up with on my own:

```
TF = []
for i in arr1: 
    if i in arr2:
        TF.append(True)
    else:
        TF.append(False)
new_data = data[TF]
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this that doesn't involve a for loop?  I should mention that the arrays themselves are being input from an external file, and there are actually multiple arrays of data, so I can't really change anything about that.

Comment: It seems like nobody can ever find the [set routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.set.html) in the docs. (The fact that none of the individual functions link to the list of them, instead all referring to `numpy.lib.arraysetopts` and making you guess how to search of that, probably doesn't help. But the modern docs with the navbar at the top should have solved that problem…)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d), which tests whether each element in one array is also present in the second array.

**Demo**

```
>>> new_data = data[np.in1d(arr1, arr2)]
>>> new_data
array([ 80.,  99.])
```

`in1d` returns an `ndarray` of bools, which is analogous to the list you constructed in your original code:

```
>>> np.in1d(arr1, arr2)
array([False, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```